# Why did the Torah have to mention the thigh of Yakov?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashas-shemos

In Parshas Shemos 1:5, when describing the children of Yakov the Torah uses the phrase "yerech Yakov" to describe where they came from. Some Rishonim explain that the Torah is using using clean language, and using the phrase "the thigh of Yakov" instead of saying "the genitalia of Yakov." Why did the Torah have to even mention this idea of where on Yakov's body they came from?  What would be so bad with saying that they descended from Yakov or something like that?

Comment: Have you compared other genealogies in Tanakh? This could just be an idiom which doesn't translate well (as with most idioms)

Comment: @DoubleAA. In the TaNach itself we find at least 5 other ways to refer to this. And I myself could add a few more. The last example I would choose would be "the ones who came out from Yakov's eiver" !

Comment: Even to this day יוצאי חלציך is an accepted idiom. And in English too https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fruit_of_one's_loins . What you would choose last is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @DoubleAA. So you're saying that the answer is that whatever was a common idiom at the time the Torah was written, was used by Hashem when writing the Torah, even if it was not the "cleanest" or more proper way of referring to it?

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't the most proper way of saying it. I didn't even claim that idiom was popular then. Just the God chose this phrase and it doesn't seem inappropriate as we find similar idioms which aren't inappropriate.

Comment: See [here](http://www.cckollel.org/parsha_encounters/5769/shemos.pdf), first piece for a possible explanation.

Comment: see Bereshis 46:26